# To trigger every time with .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to have a `.click()` on a `<a>` to find out it wont trigger every time I click, what it suppose to do is open a dialog.

That is not the only problem I would need to pass a value to my jquery to. I just cant figure this one out.

I need it to be a `<a>` because it's gone be in a dropdown menu. Do you got any suggestions?

**EDIT**
this is the code I use and it workes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false, bgiframe: true, modal: true, height: 600, width: 1000, Close: function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); } });

        $('a').live('click', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var ids = $(this).attr('id');
            var first = "<iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' src='" + "" + "'</iframe>'";
            $('.iframe').html(ids);

            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
```

This code intilise the dialog, open on every click and it work every time, trick for me here was the 'destroy' at the end and the inilise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will trigger on every click. Whilst I doubt this will be the case, check you haven't got any other event handlers listening on the 'a', that are applying `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. Try adding a `return false` to the end of the click handler, or even better:

```
$('a').click(function(evt) {
        var first = "<iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' src='" + need to put value here + "'</iframe>'";
        $('.iframe').html(first);
        $('#dialog').dialog({ bgiframe: true, modal: true, height: 600, width: 1000 });

        evt.preventDefault();
    });
```

You might find that the page is reloading if you're not preventing the default action of the anchor tag, which would give the impression nothing is happening.

What sort of "value" are you thinking of? You can use jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store information, and of course you have access to all global variables in that scope.

**EDIT:**
To answer your comment, you can retrieve the ID of the a inside the click event as follows:

```
var theIdOfTheA = $(this).attr('id');
```

Note that this must be placed inside the handler.

**EDIT2:**

```
$('a').live('click', function(evt) {
        var first = "<iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' src='" + $(this).attr('id') + "'</iframe>'";
        $('.iframe').html(first);
        $('#dialog').dialog({ bgiframe: true, modal: true, height: 600, width: 1000 });

        evt.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Every 'a' gone have a id value and its that value I want to pass to the click()

Comment: One thing tho it wont trigger more then once

Comment: It will do, unless the `a`'s are being replaced. Only the `a` tags that are in the DOM when the event handler is bound will work. If you need this to work for other `a`'s, see my edit.. otherwise can you update your post with the code you're using?

Comment: My bad it was working only thing that wont work is the dialog now. I need to look into that. if you got any suggestions pls let me know

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/olalu/edit

make sure you **close** the dialog before open it again!

```
<a href='javascript:;' id='my_unique_id' >click</a>
```

**EDITED**

```
$('a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var theIdOfTheA = this.id;

    var first = "<iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' src='" + 
                "http://www.sf.se" + "'</iframe>'";
      $('.iframe').html(theIdOfTheA);
       $('#dialog').dialog({  
       bgiframe: true, 
       modal: true, 
       height: 600, 
       width: 1000, 
       //this
       Close: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); },
       //OR this OR both
       Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
    });
 });
```

Comment: This might be it for the close but The code is not right. It wont open it now

Comment: works to open it was my bad i missed one }, still wont fire twice with dialog tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data into an event handler by doing the following (from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)):

```
$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event, param1, param2) {
  alert(param1 + "\n" + param2);
});
$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);
```

So you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').bind("click", function(event, myValue) {
        var first = "<iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' src='" + myValue + "'</iframe>'";
        $('.iframe').html(first);
        $('#dialog').dialog({ bgiframe: true, modal: true, height: 600, width: 1000 });
    });
});
```

Note that you are now using bind() to bind the event handler, and the function is receiving a value (name it whatever you want). To show google in the iframe:

```
$('a').trigger('click', ['http://www.google.com']);
```

Comment: I don't get this code in that way how I should use the trigger? because I'm gone have like 20-30 'a' and they gone have different values that should gone be used.